# How to split and display a WordPress custom post type database with two WP_Query?

Tags: php, wordpress

Is it possible to split a custom post type blog DB (8 posts in all for now) and set two WP_Query arrays to spit out on two different sections with a `if`, `while`, and `foreach` loop to display them?

I've added the `echo` just to see what the array structure would come out to, but it seems like the first set `feature_query` doesn't show anything and everything is showing up in `archived_query` even though I targeted the first set with specific `tags` in order to isolate them.enter code here

```
// featured set of 4
$feature_query = new WP_Query(array(
  'post_type' => 'experience-blog',
  'orderby' => 'date',
  'order' => 'DESC',
  'tag' => 'featured',
  'post__in' => array(
      array(
    'tag' => 'featured'
      )
   )
));

echo '<pre>';
print_r($feature_query);
echo '</pre>';


// the rest of the blog posts from the DB
$archive_query = new WP_Query(array(
  'post_type' => 'experience-blog',
  'orderby' => 'date',
  'order' => 'DESC',
  'tag' => '',
  'post__not_in' => array(
      array(
    'tag' => ''
      )
   )
));

echo '<pre>';
print_r($archive_query);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: `post__in` is supposed to be an array of post ids. What you are trying to pass to it, makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: If you want to get the "opposite" of what filtering by `'tag' => 'featured'` gets you - then use `tag__not_in`. (That expects an array and the actual tag ID, you can not work with the slug in that one.)

Comment: Thanks @CBroe, I will make that switch. 

But what do you add to `tag__not_in` if you want it to show everything else except for the `featured` items? I searched around and people said you can write `'tag__not_in' => array( 2, 6),` however, I don't want to just target a handful of archived items, I need the rest.

Comment: Well you put the id of the `featured` tag into the array ...? _"I need the rest"_ - is anything unclear about what "not in" means?